# Facebook relationship status hidden from my partner’s timeline

Tags: facebook

I was going through my girlfriend’s timeline and she doesn’t have any relationship status showing on her timeline or under the “about me” section anymore. I went to mine and it only says “in a relationship” now, but it doesn’t have her name tagged anymore like it used to be. I was thinking that she could have hidden it from her timeline and that’s why her name is not tagged on mine anymore, but I wanted to make sure first.

What happens to the other person’s relationship status when you hide yours?